# Firefox and Flash change from firebug

Tags: javascript, html, flash, firefox

I'm trying to write a Playlist for Flash Player. So I have problem with Flash & firefox. The playlist is HTML list where I have file urls for MP3. When I change from firebug object  value the firefox doesn't react - disapears.

**Upd:** I have object where I have parameters, when I change for example parameter where is written file path, the firefox doesn't react, flash player still using file path which received when page loads.

**Update 2:** Very very strange! When I change in firebug, it's ok. When I do same steps with jquery, flash gives this error: `You are missing some Flash content that should appear here! Perhaps your browser cannot display it, or maybe it did not initialize correctly.`

My jquery looks like this:

```
    $('div.filefield-file a').click(function () {
    $('object object').attr({data: "temp"});
    var newMusic = $(this)[0].href;
    alert(newMusic);
    var newFlashVars = "playerID=12646923621&autostart=no&loop=no&soundFile="+newMusic;
    /*$('object object').attr({data: "temp"});*/
    $('object object param[name=flashvars]').attr('value',newFlashVars);
    $('object object').attr({data: "http://spp/sites/all/modules/swftools/shared/1pixelout/player.swf"});
});
```

Comment: can you clarify the question a little bit - may be with some code?

Comment: I have object where I have parameters, when I change for example parameter where is written file path, the firefox doesn't react, flash player still using file path which received when page loads.

Comment: have you tried reloading the Flash alone (in Firebug, change the `src` to something else then back)?

Comment: Yeah good idea :)) Firstly I change <object>'s data value, then I'm changing param value, then object value back. Work's!! :))

Thanks!!

Comment: Very very strange! When I change in firebug, it's ok. When I do same steps with jquery, flash gives this error: You are missing some Flash content that should appear here! Perhaps your browser cannot display it, or maybe it did not initialize correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I drop custom code writing, and I'm using now FlowPlayer, it is supporting Audio, Video and Images. Also Playlist :)